# want mongo query to do string regex start && contains && end

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to mongo query with regex which will return the document

name match start with 'abc' and

name match contains 'efg'  and

name match end with 'ijk'

```
var start =  'abc[\\s\\S]*';
var cont =  '[\\s\\S]*efg[\\s\\S]*';
var end =  '[\\s\\S]*ijk';

db.getCollection().find({
 "$and":[
    {
        "name":{"$regex":new RegExp('^' + start + '$', 'i')}
    },
    {
        "name":{"$regex":new RegExp('^' + cont + '$', 'i')}
    },
    {
        "name":{"$regex":new RegExp('^' + end + '$', 'i')}
    }]
})
```

This runs very slow need some better query or suggestion...

Comment: Are there any indexes on this collection?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). Once you put an `$` to match from the end of the string then **"no index can be used"**. Like all databases, MongoDB can only efficiently search with an index from the **"beginiing"** of the string only. If you need something matching "parts" of a string, then try to "tokenize" and split up individual words into an array and match on those instead. With either equality matches or `$regex` *"from the beginning of the string only"*. Anything else, scans the whole collection.

Comment: @dilsingi yes i have created indexes...

Comment: @NeilLunn but in my case i cant split it as a word by space because its a complete word without any space. This query input will come from user so we cant determine anything...

Comment: is that possible to combine all conditions to one regex ?
Example: abc*efg*ijk 
Result: 

{abc}dddd{efg}zzzzz{ijk}