# MongoDB regex string startswith and endswith

Tags: json, regex, mongodb

So i have something that looks like this

```
db.usuarios.insert
(
    [
        {
            "nome" : "neymala",
            "idade" : 40,
            "status" : "solteira"
        },
        {
            "nome" : "gabriel",
            "idade" : 31,
            "status" : "casado"
        },
        {
            "nome" : "jose",
            "idade" : 25,
            "status" : "solteiro"
        },
        {
            "nome" : "manoel",
            "idade" : 25,
            "status" : "solteiro",
            "interesses" : [
                "esporte",
                "musica"
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

I would like to find names that starts with ma and ends with l, for example "manoel" or "manuel"

I have figured out how to do one or the other with the fallowing querys:

```
db.usuarios.find({nome:{$regex: /^ma/ }})

db.usuarios.find({nome:{$regex: /l$/ }})
```

Now i would like to combine them into a single query.

Comment: Also refer to [want mongo query to do string regex start && contains && end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44738577/2313887) since this is one of the worst things you can possibly do. All query forms will not be able to use an index

Answer (score 31):

You can combine the two requirements into a single regex:

```
db.usuarios.find({nome: /^ma.*l$/})
```

In a regex, `.*` means to match 0 or more of any character. So this regex matches names that start with `ma` and end with `l`, ignoring whatever is between.

Answer (score 15):

combine both querys with a AND opetator

```
db.usuarios.find({
$and:[
    {nome:{$regex: /^ma/ }},
    {nome:{$regex: /l$/ }}
]

})
```

Comment: The answer is right, but `$regex` is not necessary here. `{nome: /^ma/}` is fine.

Answer (score 11):

In javascript `/.../` is a regex, so no `$regex` needed.

```
db.usuarios.find({
    $and:[
        {nome: /^ma/ },
        {nome: /l$/ }
    ]
})
```

Also note `starts with` can hit an index. `ends with` can't. This way you'd better have a selective `starts with`, otherwise there will be lots of object scans which may occupy extra CPU and possibly slow down your query.

Comment: A workaround to improve the performance of endswith would be to insert your documents with a duplicate of that field, but with the contents reversed.

Answer (score 1):

May be this code help you.

you can search small letter string and capital letter string.......

[image]

Comment: This works, but just know that there are performance considerations.  Regex are not collation aware, so indexes cannot be used when doing case-insensitive regular expression matching.  This means that mongo must perform a collection scan.